# React native ejected expo on OSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

### Question:

Is there an issue with Expo + OSX and ejected apps or have I done something wrong while attempting to run an ejected react-native/expo app?

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out via stackoverflow and my own debugging.

I am attempting to run an ejected React Native Expo app on OSX and am having trouble, I may be missing a step.

Any help is appreciated.

Steps to reproduce (OSX):

## 1. Install new expo app

`expo init`

## 2. Eject expo app

`cd appname && expo eject`

## 3. Install native modules

`cd ios && pod install && cd ../`

## 4. Run react project

`react-native run-ios`

FYI I have installed node modules.

This runs the simulator and launches the app however it immediately closes before anything is visible.

I launched Xcode in an attempt to get more information, when launching via a simulated phone via Xcode I get some kind of memory error. Keep in mind this is a fresh expo application.

`Thread 7: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

These aren't always the same error but they always look similar, some kind of lower level language than I'm use to.

**Versions**:

- node - 12.7.0
- npm - 6.13.7
- expo - 3.13.1
- react-native-cli - 2.0.1
- react-native - 0.61.4
- SDK 36

> ### Question:
>
> Is there an issue with Expo + OSX and ejected apps or have I done something wrong while >attempting to run an ejected react-native/expo app?

Comment: try running `npm i` after ejecting?

Comment: What expo SDK did you use?

Comment: @Jacob I have installed node modules...

Comment: @Phạm Tấn Tài SDK36

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through this same issue, with multiple different errors, and it just turned out that I needed to upgrade all of these the latest versions

- macOS
- Node / NPM
- Cocoapods
- Xcode